# Join vs Navigation property for sub lists in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have a sql statement like this:

```
DECLARE @destinations table(destinationId int)
INSERT INTO @destinations
VALUES (414),(416)

SELECT *
FROM GroupOrder grp (NOLOCK)
          JOIN DestinationGroupItem destItem (NOLOCK)
                    ON destItem.GroupOrderId = grp.GroupOrderId
          JOIN @destinations dests
                    ON destItem.DestinationId = dests.destinationId
WHERE OrderId = 5662
```

I am using entity framework and I am having a hard time getting this query into Linq.  (The only reason I wrote the query above was to help me conceptualize what I was looking for.)

I have an IQueryable of GroupOrder entities and a List of integers that are my destinations.

After looking at this I realize that I can probably just do two joins (like my SQL query) and get to what I want.

But it seems a bit odd to do that because a GroupOrder object already has a list of DestinationGroupItem objects on it.

I am a bit confused how to use the Navigation property on the GroupOrder when I have an IQueryable listing of GroupOrders.

Also, if possible, I would like to do this in one trip to the database.  (I think I could do a few `foreach` loops to get this done, but it would not be as efficient as a single IQueryable run to the database.)

NOTE: I prefer fluent linq syntax over the query linq syntax.  But beggars can't be choosers so I will take whatever I can get.

Comment: Have you tried [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) it does conversions from SQL to LINQ (unlike [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) which does LINQ to SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the DestinationGroupItem as a Navigation-property, then you already have your SQL-JOIN equivalent - [example](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first). Load the related entities with [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx). Use List's Contains extension method to see if the desired DestinationId(s) is(are) hit:

```
var destinations = new List<int> { 414, 416 };
var query = from order in GroupOrder.Include(o => o.DestinationGroupItem) // this is the join via the navigation property
            where order.OrderId == 5662 && destinations.Contain(order.DestinationGroupItem.DestinationId)
            select order;
// OR
var query = dataContext.GroupOrder
            .Include(o => o.DestinationGroupItem)
            .Where(order => order.OrderId == 5662 && destinations.Contain(order.DestinationGroupItem.DestinationId));
```

Comment: I need a separate object for each item in the DestinationGroupItem list.

Comment: i enhanced the code in my answer. i have forgotten the destinations

Comment: A quick question. Wouldn't this be more efficient if `.Where()` was placed before `.Include()` ?

Comment: @Celdor to be honest ... I don't know. I couldn't find any documentation regarding this matter and I haven't tested it.